# Copying a file onto several other files with different names

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have one file (lets call it *file1.xyz*) that I want to use as a template to work on. I need to copy the contents of *file1.xyz* so that they replace the contents of the other files - *file2.xyz*, *file3.xyz*, *file4.xyz*, *file5.xyz*.....*file70.xyz* whilst keeping the original file name.

I have tried using:

```
cp file1.xyz *.xyz
```

The files are all in the same directory and I don't want to append them to each other.

This has not worked, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Blindly copy it to all other "fellow" files inside a directory?

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
f=(file*.xyz)
cat $f[1] > $f[2,-1]
```

That writes all output files in parallel though (as if using `tee`) which means that doesn't scale well to large number of files.

With any Bourne-like shell (including `zsh` and `bash`), you could always do:

```
set file*.xzy
source=$1; shift
for dest do cp "$source" "$dest"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner that would create the files in your example:

```
for i in {2..70}; do cp file1.xyz file$i.xyz; done
```

Comment: Since the question has a Bash tag, you can also substitute `\`seq 2 70\`` with `{2..70}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo file{2..70}.xyz | xargs -n 1 -t cp file1.xyz
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way you can do by tee command

```
cat file1.xyz | tee *.xyz >/dev/null
```

Comment: This does not create the files file2.xyz through file70.xyz

Comment: Author is asking about to replace the content of file,so i thought the file is already there

Comment: I see, you're right -- the OP does imply that the other files are already there. Your solution accomplishes that.